# Form submits continuously in FB.api method

Tags: javascript, facebook, submit

Somewhere in my code I call the FB.api method :

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  var access_token =  FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
  document.getElementById('status').value = access_token;
  document.getElementById("tokenForm").submit();
});
```

The problem is that the form with the id `tokenForm` submits continuously not only once and I can.t figure out why .

Comment: could you post the complete code with html dom structure & if possible create  a jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bxsus7pL/ here it is . thank you

Comment: Does the form submit multiple times when you hit the `login` each time or just hitting once form is submitting multiple times ?

Comment: hitting the button once triggers the submit continuously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use your `statusChangeCallback` as callback not only for `FB.login`, but for `FB.getLoginStatus` as well.

The latter will also return a response object with a `status` value of `'connected'`, once the user did login – and so on every new page load `FB.getLoginStatus` calls the callback function with that status, and that then triggers your `testAPI` function, which makes the `/me` request and then submits the form – again … and again … and again.